# Unity - How to run 2 different IEnumerator Methods at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Lets say you have one IEnumerator method that lowers the hp bar slowly using time.deltatime and then another IEnumerator method that lowers the hp text that contains the current hp number, that way you have a nice animation effect of both the bar and health number.

But doing something like this when you call them, it would only run it one by one:

```
    //updating the hp stat and UI Text
    yield return UpdateHP();
    //Updating the HP Bar gameobject using transform.localScale.x
    yield return UpdateHPBar();
```

I'm not an expert on IEnumerator methods/coroutines but is there any way I can tell it to run both IEnumerator methods at the same time? Would appreciate any help thanks.

Also would appreciate some examples on how one would run two IEnumerator methods simultaneously.

Comment: Your examples don't have anything to do with Unity Coroutines. Unity Coroutines only `yield return` a delay before the coroutine continues, your sample code is something else entirely

Comment: My question is about how would you run two coroutines at the same time, theres no code , I just wanna know the concept of how one would accomplish something like that. My example is just to show how the order would execute if I called those two methods

Comment: I changed the title a bit to hopefully clarify it, sorry if I didn't describe it properly

Comment: What if you just return a tuple? `yield return (updateHP(), updateHPBar())`

Comment: @MichaelWelch Thanks for the suggestion, I tested it and it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Coroutines by their very nature run in (pseudo-)parallel.  You just have to start them at the same time. ```void DoThings() { StartCoroutine( Coroutine1(data) ); StartCoroutine( Coroutine2(data) ); }```

Comment: _"doing something like this when you call them, it would only run it one by one"_ -- without more context, it's impossible to know what _"like this"_ actually is. It sounds like you have a single coroutine that you intend to handle more than one thing. If so, don't do that. Put the two different needs into two different coroutines, and start both. Alternatively, it's possible you can call both methods in each iteration of the coroutine and choose something else to return. Without a [mcve], it's impossible to understand the context of your question. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in the comments by Immersive

> Coroutines by their very nature run in (pseudo-)parallel. You just have to start them at the same time. `void DoThings() { StartCoroutine( Coroutine1(data) ); StartCoroutine( Coroutine2(data) ); }`

However if anyone wants to show alternatives or a better way then feel free to post it. Thank you!